# Creating folder in view where I can put my other views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I just got a question about the controller management.

I just try to get folder in my `view/{copntroller}/newFolder/currentView`.

I was trying to use maprouting, but that doesn't work well(doesn't work at all :D).

I just try to put this code in "`RouteConfig.cs`"

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Admin",
               url: "{controller}/{Folder}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

[Here is a picture of current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBrLY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing doesn't change Views location search. It change `Url` routing (Read like: Understand what Controller method call when user sends request, **but not what View use to render**).

If you want change your default View search locations you should redefine `ViewEngine` like this:

```
 public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine //Here you inherit from current ViewEngine
 {
    public CustomViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
           //That's your Views loactions
           "~/Views/{1}/Create/{0}.cshtml",   
           "~/Views/{1}/Edit/{0}.cshtml",  
        };
    }
 }
```

Here `{0}` - is Your Contoller method name (Action), `{1}` - Controller name.

You can define many different locations and ViewEngine will search in defined order.

The last thing you should do is register your `CustomViewEngine` in  `global.asax.cs` method `Application_Start()` like this:

```
 ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
 ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.